# HTTP multirange requests - headers in response

Tags: http, curl, httprequest

I'm using multirange http requests like this
"curl --range 1-2,2-3 http://some.url"
The response is like

> --00000000000000030705 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Range: bytes 1-2/13882393
>
> il
>   --00000000000000030705 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Range: bytes 2-3/13882393
>
> le
>   --00000000000000030705--

How can I remove fields Content-Type and Content-Range from response to get a raw data from server (without parsing on client side)?
I want to get response like:
"ille"

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't. The server is conforming to the spec, as described [by the RFC](http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7233.html#status.206).

> If multiple parts are being transferred, the server generating the 206 response must generate a "multipart/byteranges" payload, as defined in Appendix A, and a Content-Type header field containing the multipart/byteranges media type and its required boundary parameter. To avoid confusion with single-part responses, a server must not generate a Content-Range header field in the HTTP header section of a multiple part response (this field will be sent in each part instead).

In the case of contiguous multi ranges the server may send the response without the multipart boundaries but this is optional.

> When multiple ranges are requested, a server may coalesce any of the ranges that overlap, or that are separated by a gap that is smaller than the overhead of sending multiple parts, regardless of the order in which the corresponding byte-range-spec appeared in the received Range header field. Since the typical overhead between parts of a multipart/byteranges payload is around 80 bytes, depending on the selected representation's media type and the chosen boundary parameter length, it can be less efficient to transfer many small disjoint parts than it is to transfer the entire selected representation.

Within the header area of each body part in the multipart payload, the server must generate a Content-Range header field corresponding to the range being enclosed in that body part. If the selected representation would have had a Content-Type header field in a 200 (OK) response, the server should generate that same Content-Type field in the header area of each body part. For example:

Assuming your server conforms to the spec, sending a single range 1-3 you will get a single body.